# How can I set multiple default values (an array) for an element with maxOccurs > 1?

Tags: arrays, xml, xsd, default

I have an `XSD` schema with a complex type that contains a string element with `minOccurs="2"` and `maxOccurs="2"` (an array of strings):

```xml
<xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" name="image" type="xs:string"/>
```

I tried to set a default value this way:

```
<xs:element default="['cat.png', 'dog.png']" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" name="image" type="xs:string"/>
```

and applied to the `xml`:

```xml
<image></image>
<image></image>
```

But instead of having 'cat.png' and 'dog.png', I get `['cat.png', 'dog.png']` twice, because the type is a string and that is a valid string.

Can't I set multiple default values for elements with cardinality > 1 in some way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such mechanism available. Your ideas for such a mechanism are highly creative but bear no relationship to anything in the spec.

For a start, you should note that default values for elements do not apply when the element is absent, they only apply when the element is present but empty.

Furthermore, default values for elements are always simple strings, so they make no sense with an element-only content model.

Comment: So must I change model? I have not to use `sequence`?

Comment: Ok think about this: I have in xsd `<xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" name="image" type="xs:string"/>` and in xml `<image></image><image></image>`. The elements are present but empty. If I specify `default="cat.png"`, I get two cats. Can't I specify a default like `"cat.png", "dog.png"` in some way (not with the `default` attribute, because it's impossible)?

Comment: No, you can't. The defaulting mechanism in XSD is very limited. Not quite as limited as in DTDs, but almost.